# clojure convert lazy-seq to hash map

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I'm a clojure beginner. How do I create a map from a lazySeq?

```
(def fields [:name :age :color])
(def values ["joe" 32 "red"])
(def record (interleave fields values))

(def mymap (into {} record))  ;; ????

;; (get mymap :age)
;; 32
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To answer your actual question:

```
(apply hash-map record)
```

But since you actually already have separate keys and values, I would suggest skipping the interleave step and instead writing

```
(zipmap fields values)
```

Or if you have your heart set on `into`, you could

```
(into {} (map vector fields values))
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't sensible at all, but since the original question wanted to use `into` with `record`:

`(into {} (map vec (partition 2 record)))`

Comment: In what way is this alternative not sensible (not a rhetorical question, a genuine question)? Is it because it's longer and / or more elaborate than the other alternatives, i.e., it's "beating around the bush??

Comment: It also silently drops a value instead of throwing an exception, if `record` unexpectedly has an odd number of elements. Although on reflection, I suppose the solutions that make use of the separate key and value sequences have a similar issue.